# Diophantine equation $z=(ax+by+c)/(dxy)$, references?

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, diophantine-equations, problem-solving

I am looking for some sources (books or papers) which discuss the Diophantine equation
$$
z=\frac{ax+by+c}{dxy}
$$
where $a,b,c,d$ are given positive integers. Could anyone give some references?
Thanks.

Comment: Where did you get this diophantine equation from?